# JSP request.getParameter("..") always returning null for select tag

Tags: html, jsp

I have the following html code that is basically a drop down list. Select has the attribute name `report`, and the option tags values differ based on a for statement that I have put.

```
<form method="post" name="reportlist">
   <select name="report" style=" width: 40%; float: left; margin-left: 10px">
        <%
           for (...)
           {
         %>
               <option value="<%out.print(...);%>"><%out.print(...);%></option> 
         <%              
           }
          %>

<input type="button" name="Go" value="Go" onClick="window.location='anotherpagename.jsp?variable=<%out.print(request.getParameter("report"));%>'">

   </select>
</form>
```

`request.getParameter("report")` is ALWAYS returning null, although I want the value of the option tag selected to be returned. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem is your input button does not submits the form. Correct the tag as:

```html
<form action="your url">
  <select name="report">
    <!-- your rest of the logic -->
  </select>
  <input type="submit" value="Go" /> <!-- use `submit` instead of `button` -->
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

The parameter `report` will only be present in the request that you'll send when **submitting** the form containing the select.

You're expecting the parameter to be present when **generating** that form. That can't possibly work. At that time, the user hasn't seen the form yet, and has thus not selected anything, and has not yet sent his choice to the server.

You should learn your basics:

- how HTTP works
- how to use the JSP EL and the JSTL, and avoid using scriptlets in the JSP
- how to use the JSTL to escape values that can contain HTML special characters, or even malicious data submitted by the user.